# CakePHP: how can i handle general model functions?

Tags: cakephp

I have some "global" functions not directly related to a model that need to be called from different controllers.
Where can i put them and how can they be correctly called from a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your functions do. CakePHP has two generic classes: `AppController` and `AppModel`. Every controller should extend `AppController` and every model should extend `AppModel` so the methods in these to classes should be available to you in every controller.

Another alternative is to package the functions as behaviors and have all models `actAs` them.

Depending on semantics you may want to choose one over the other options.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to create your own **helper** class if you want to use in views OR create your own **component** to use in controllers.

And group the related function in a single and give a meaningful name.

Such that you can use it in your any project just by copying them to your project.

Just add those files to your code wherever required by using the global array `var $helpers = array('your_helper1','helper2');` and for components you can use `var $components = array('your_component1','component2');`

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like a behavior to me if the data is model related.
if it is just some general method, use a component instead.

can you be more specific about the methods you want to use globally?